# How to get a list of field names of a queryset in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a queryset whose fields are being selected with a multiple choice filter. So I wonder how can I get a list of field names of a query of this set.

Person.objects.all() :

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Josh', 'surname': 'Smith', 'age': 28, 'address': 'New York'}]>
```

What I'm trying to get :

```
['name', 'surname', 'age', 'address']
```

** Update:

Found a solution:

```
list(Person.objects.all().values()[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this to use **queryset._fields**

Comment: It gives me None. I found a solution: list(Person.objects.all().values()[0])